# What is the difference between style prop and general props of View in react native?

Tags: react-native

I put "what is the difference" in the title meaning how exactly they are similar and how they are different. Basically, how does the `style` prop work on `View`?

There are some keys that can be put either into style or into props. For example, `<View shadowRadius={3}>` vs `<View style={{shadowRadius:3}}>`. Does this choice affect anything? If not, what is the point of this?